# Piano: Left handed Gmaj7 chord

Tags: piano, chords, fingering, beginner

[image]

I have trouble playing the Gmaj7 chord with my left hand.
I'm using 5-3-2-1 fingering, but I can't avoid hitting the A key with my 4th finger.

What exercises or techniques are used to void that?

Answer (score 18):

Try shifting your hand toward the fall board (i.e., away from your body). That will bring your thumb closer to the F#, allowing additional relaxation in the rest of your hand.

So this:

[image: Recommended hand position]

Rather than this:

[image: Non-Recommended hand position]

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your fingers are curved not flat.   Maybe they need to be further forward on the keys.

Play down the Gmaj7 chord.  Keep the notes held down, play a series of A notes with your 4th finger.  You'll find it pretty tricky!  Try not to lock your hand - relax!  But it will teach you to lift that finger independently.

Answer (score 1):

Consider rootless voicings -- start on F#, then B and D (or voice it B,D,F#, that works too).

http://www.thejazzpianosite.com/jazz-piano-lessons/jazz-chord-voicings/rootless-voicings/